# python-social-auth redirect to the user profile in Django

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I am using the wonderful `python-social-auth`package, and more precisely the `social-auth-app-django` version since my project is using the Django Framework.

Once the user is registered/logged in via any social backend, I'd like to redirect the user to their own very user profile.

I know I can set a static URL in my `settings.py`such as:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/logged-in/'
```

But how can I dynamically redirect the user to their profile given that I know their username/slug?

If I could set variables in the `settings.py` it'd be something like:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/<slug:slug>/'
```

But of course I can't do that.

Is there any way I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Did you figure it out?